# Powerpoint vertical animation for long image

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, scrolling, animation

I have a client who wants to display a Powerpoint presentation rotating on large TV screens in a shopping center. The artwork, however, is portrait layout wile the TVs are Full HD televisions.

Is there a way that I can make these slides aligned top and center, and then let Powerpoint do an animation to "scroll the image up" until the bottom of the image is reached, then animate to the next slide and do it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I managed to figure out the search terms for Google to get the desired search results, I happened upon this link:

https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-scroll-an-image-in-powerpoint

It put me on the right track to get the job done.